# All possible ways to split n over k groups - R

Tags: r, math, combinations

I am stuck in a mathematical problem. I would like to make a function that outputs all the ways an integer "n" can be divide into "k" groups in such a way that in each group "k" is at least 1 (k >= 1).

The function could look something like:

```
n_ways <- function(n,k) {...}
```

I would like a dataFrame as an output. So for: **n_ways(5,3)**

```
     A  B  C
1    3  1  1
2    1  3  1
3    1  1  3
4    2  2  1
5    2  1  2
6    1  2  2
```

The order in which the solutions are presented in the dataFrame is not important.

I looked for solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753987/find-all-possible-ways-to-split-a-list-of-elements-into-a-a-given-number-of-grou) and in other languages like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395235/create-all-possible-ways-of-putting-n-users-into-k-groups) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344316/an-iterative-rather-than-recursive-algorithm-to-find-all-ways-to-split-n-into-m). Unfortunately I am not that good to make a function that suits my problem based on this, but hopefully you are.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `partitions` package:

```
library(partitions)
t(compositions(5, 3, FALSE))
#[1,] 3 1 1
#[2,] 2 2 1
#[3,] 1 3 1
#[4,] 2 1 2
#[5,] 1 2 2
#[6,] 1 1 3
```

From the respective help file

> Function compositions() returns all 2^(n-1) ways of partitioning an integer; thus 4 + 1 + 1 is distinct from 1 + 4 + 1 or 1 + 1 + 4.

Comment: Thank you so much. Clean and easy. Have a good one and again.. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities:

```
eg <- expand.grid(rep(list(1:5), 3))
unique(eg[which(rowSums(eg)==5),])
```

which results in:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
3     3    1    1
7     2    2    1
11    1    3    1
27    2    1    2
31    1    2    2
51    1    1    3
```

Or use the [combinat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/combinat/) (but this samples without replacement)

```
library(combinat)
combn(5, 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
# [2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
# [3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5
```

Comment: `combn` already exists in base R. No need for `combinat`. Also, not sure OP wants this. Given their desired output, it seems to me that they want k integers that sums to n.

Comment: Thanks @csgillespie for the fast response, but I am not able to get your output matched with my desired output. for n_ways(5,3) (or another function) there should be only 6 answers possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution, 
it is not very fast, but it could be a starting point for you to improve the speed.

```
n_ways <- function(n, k){

    addend <- rep(seq(1,n),k)

    combinations <- combn(x = addend, m = k)

    combinations <- t(combinations[,which(colSums(combinations) == n)])

    return(unique(combinations))
}

n_ways(5,3)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    2
#[2,]    1    3    1
#[3,]    1    1    3
#[4,]    2    1    2
#[5,]    2    2    1
#[6,]    3    1    1
```

If you are interested in, I can write some comments to the function, but it consists of R base functions as `colSums` or `combn`.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. It works exactly like I asked and I can see what actually is happening :)  Thanks and have a good day!