# split total sum K ways combinatorics python

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have a total amount of density N. I need to find all the ways I can split that density into k groups, assuming some minimally divisible portion d.

So, if N=4, k=3, d=1, i need:

```
[
    (1, 1, 2),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (2, 1, 1),
]
```

If N=5, k=3, d=1:

```
[
    (1, 1, 3),
    (1, 3, 1),
    (3, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 2),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (2, 2, 1),
]
```

Feels like this should conform to some basic combinatorics problem, but I can't think of it. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435018/all-possible-ways-to-split-n-over-k-groups-r) reference a very similar operation in R, but not python.

One naive way of doing things is to filter the result of `itertools.product` to only the tuples which sum to N, but that feels inelegant:

```py
import itertools


def compositions(N, k, d=1):
    for seq in itertools.product(*[range(d, N, d)] * k):
        if sum(seq) == N:
            yield seq
```

Example

```py
>>> list(compositions(7, 3))
[(1, 1, 5),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (1, 4, 2),
 (1, 5, 1),
 (2, 1, 4),
 (2, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 2),
 (2, 4, 1),
 (3, 1, 3),
 (3, 2, 2),
 (3, 3, 1),
 (4, 1, 2),
 (4, 2, 1),
 (5, 1, 1)]
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that d=1 because if not then you can normalize N with d, that is N' = N/d and now d=1.

The code looks as follows:

```
import itertools

def divisions(N, k):
    for q in itertools.combinations(range(N - 1), k - 1):
        yield [j - i for i, j in zip((-1,) + q, q + (N - 1,))]

answer = [x for x in divisions(7, 3)]
print(answer)
```